# How to control spike timings and the number of spikes in the Izhikevich model in the context of Rebound burst?

Tags: computational-modeling, model

We are using Izhikevich neurons for our study. We want to tweak the parameters to be able to control the number of spikes and spike timing when the negative current is removed. With the parameters given in "rebound burst" [section of code written by Izhikevich](http://www.izhikevich.org/publications/figure1.m), the spikes occur after 20 to 30 milliseconds of negative current is removed as show in the figure.
[image]

But we want the spikes to occur after 3 to 4 milliseconds of negative current being removed. How to find suitable parameters for our case?
From Trial and error, we found that tuning the parameter "c" can control the number of spikes, but am unable to figure out ways to change spike timing.